# TextView goes behind another textview during animation

Tags: java, android

I want to use property animation that moves view from left to right,like this

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView1, "translationX", 400);
```

but when animation starts, this animation is covered by view on the right of target view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3kTL.png)

I want textView1 on the top of textView2 when animation start.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `textview1.bringToFront();` before starting the animation.